# PPP Link Protocol was terminated, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ppp, dial-up

I am trying to set up a dial up connection through a Windows 7 server to Windows XP server and keep receiving the above error.  I have confirmed the username and password are correct and have tried every variation of network setting I can think of and am at a loss.  Do anyone have any suggestions on settings or have a walk through on how to set this up in Windows 7?